# Microsoft SQL Server - Multi-user solution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, sql-server

My team and I are currently trying to apply multi-user techniques in our projects. So far we have used an ArcGIS Enterprise build for this purpose but we quickly learned there are a few limitations. (One of them being lack of topology).

As a solution to our needs, we have installed an SQL Express server with a workgroup licence. I did a test on a small project with two editors and it seemed to work fine but after that, another team complained about performance. (The server does not lack resources and it is local)

Is SQL a good practice for multi-user editing in ArcMap? If so, is it worth leaving the users to edit on the DEFAULT version rather than a replica or another version?

Comment: SQL Server Express is not optimized for performance -- It is single-threaded and does not scale well. Your assertion about topology is incorrect, or at a minimum, incomplete. If, by "SQL" in the title you mean "Microsoft SQL Server" please [edit] the question (SQL is a language supported by dozens of RDBMS products).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Vince. I was indeed talking about Microsoft SQL Server. Our purpose is to create a database in which users can easily add data and work simultaneous and have the flexibility of using Arc features such as topology. As i said, we are using ArcGIS Server for multi-user editing and it is quite tedious because we have to export data for topology and then move it back for each zone we are working on. Could you offer another solution to our needs? I did a little reading and i discovered the uses of replicas but i'm still new to it in a lot of senses.

Comment: A multi user environment is definitely the way to go, either with MS SQL Server if you want to purchase a solution, or PostgreSQL if you prefer open source.  Either way, you will probably want to set up versions for each editor or working group, or at least a version for production (a single child of DEFAULT).  Maintenance can be scripted and run automatically each night if doing so manually is too tedious.